# How to split a long string of text with bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains my log information as:

```
Sat May 20 00:34:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers Sat May 20 00:35:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers Sat May 20 00:36:04 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers
```

I am trying to split this log data into lines so it looks like this:

```
Sat May 20 00:34:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers 
Sat May 20 00:35:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers 
Sat May 20 00:36:04 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any hidden line breaks after "containers"?

Comment: No. Its just a space in between containers and the next time stamp

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/containers */containers\n/g' file
Sat May 20 00:34:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers
Sat May 20 00:35:03 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers
Sat May 20 00:36:04 EST 2017 -- lane3a 4 0 -- lane3b 5 4 9 Total active sales: 4 Total bidders in sales: -- caster3a 0 -- caster3b 0 0 Total A/V 0 Estimated containers
```

or:

```
$ sed 's/\(containers\) */\1\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
perl -i.bkp -pe 's/containers/containers\n/' file.log
```

this assumes that the word `containers` is what should be at the end of every line

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole file into a Bash variable and use parameter expansion to replace spaces after `containers` by newlines:

```
text=$(< infile)
echo "${text//containers /containers$'\n'}"
```